Help with vehicle killswitch design
I am relatively new to electronics/electrical, and want to design a killswitch for my car, since it is easy to steal.
I have created the design shown below, which is intended to function like so:

if the button is not pressed and the key is turned to the run position, S1 remains open and the 5A fuse blows, immobilizing the vehicle
if the button (S1) is pressed (closed) and the key is turned to the run position, RLY1 latches open, and power goes to the vehicle control module as normal. Then, S1 can be opened whilst the vehicle is running and the fuse does not blow.

I think my design has some other useful properties. For example, the high current required to blow the fuse does not pass through the switch. However, I want to ask before I implement this - will this design work as I intend above? Secondly, do I need to add flyback diodes across each relay to prevent damage to my car?


Why not just cut the supply to the starter through a relay driven by a switch? If you use some beefy socket mount relay you could even remove the relay when not using the car. And well, mucking around with relays like this without putting it through type approval EMC testing is illegal in most countries.

Your car probably has a fuse box, and removing one crucial fuse (something like the starter motor) would do this job well.

@Lundin in most cases the starter can be jumped with a screwdriver in the fusebox, and even if not then the thief will immediately know there is a killswitch when the starter doesn't sound out

This project also has a "fun" element for me, I know there are simpler solutions

@Alex You cannot short a car relay socket with a screwdriver.

Read google snippets on google:   best kill switch for car. I like the idea of hooking the kill switch into an existing interface so that there's no "switch" to find and nobody knows it's there. You have to start the car with the door open, for example, and the left turn signal on. Then an unobtrusive green LED blinks a few times to let you know you got it.  Then engine starts normally but cuts out when you take it out of park (if green LED not lit).
